# How to set placeholder for InputText with bind-Value for formsubmit?

Tags: c#, .net, input, blazor, placeholder

I am trying to build a InputText for Blazor which holds a placeholder if the skill is yet null so is created as a new one, since I want to use the same razor component for edit and create new skill:

```html
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Skillname</label>
        @if (Skill == null)
        {
          <InputText class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Skillname" @bind-Value="Skill.Name"/>
        }
        else
        {
          <InputText @bind-Value="Skill.Name" class="form-control"/>
        }
      </div>
```

I tried to set `placeholder=".."` without having any effect. After research I found that they were using `placeholder` [here](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/building-blazor-form/) even though it is not working for me.

I only found [this possibility](https://demos.telerik.com/blazor-ui/textbox/overview) with telerik front end framework.

I was not able to find any reference to placeholder in the documentation.

Andy idea why `placeholder` is not working here or if there is any other workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no intellisense and that is what confuses people.
However, if you just use the placeholder attribute it will work.

```html
<InputText id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" @bind-Value="EmployeeVM.LastName"></InputText>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're binding to `@bind-Value="Skill.Name"` so I'm assuming `Skill` isn't null.  Your test is on `skill`, not `skill.Name`, so is never `null` you always hit the `else` option.  Try:

```
  @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(skill.Name))
    {
        ......
    }
```

And you get:

[image]

However, you don't need to do any of this as the placeholder will only display when the field is empty.